# What are these PCIe connectors that are slightly larger than SFF-8653 8i?

Tags: identification, connector, pcie, motherboard

I have some computer motherboards that ware evidently a special-order for the ASRock Rack because the vendor does not have the model listed on their website, and when I contacted them they said they didn't keep any records of its specs.

This is a dual Xeon board and appears to be for Haswell processors. I have installed two (2) Intel Xeon E5-2630L v4, although I have not yet bench tested it.

It is actually very similar to one of the motherboards they do have specs for, with the main exception of having eight (8) different large rectangular metal connectors — having dimensions of 1-3/8" wide by 5/8" thick by 3/4" deep — that are labeled `PCIE_CON1` thru `PCIE_CON8`. Pincount pin count is 2x34, I think, but it may be 2x33 or even 2x32; hard to tell for sure.

I have attached a photo of one connector clearly shown with the three others not shown as clearly.

[image]

I purchased a SlimSAS SFF-8654 8i cable thinking that that was what those connectors would connect to, but I discovered that the SFF-8654 8i is not the correct connector as it is slightly smaller in width and thickness than these connectors.

I am trying my best to figure out what type of connector/cable/backplane would support this — if a standard for one exists — and what kind of extensibility I could get out of this board *(I have a lot of these boards)*. I am hoping that I could use them to add M2 & U2 NVMe support, additional PCIe slots, and/or support for additional SATA drives. Ideally I would like to use these boards for high-capacity storage servers.

**Does anyone know what type these connectors are, or what their specifications are?**

I would, if course, also be happy to learn what components from [DigiKey](https://www.digikey.com/) or [Mouser](https://www.mouser.com/) would support these connectors — especially if nobody can point me to ready-made cables and/or extension boards — after which I could look into getting custom PCBs designed and created.

Thank you in advance for any help.

P.S. If this post would be more appropriate on a different StackExchange I would very much appreciate a comment explaining where I should post it instead.

---

### UPDATE

I was able to get a diagram for those connectors:

[image: PCIE_CON1 and PCIE_CON2]
[image: PCIE_CON3 and PCIE_CON4]
[image: PCIE_CON5 and PCIE_CON6]
[image: PCIE_CON7 and PCIE_CON8]

Comment: Dimensions, pincount etc would be useful info. Maybe also check datasheet for motherboard.

Comment: Possibly external PCIe iPass x8 connections (e.g. https://www.molex.com/molex/products/part-detail/cable_assemblies/0745460801)

Comment: @TomCarpenter — Thanks. PCIe iPass x8 looks like it might be it. I'll see if I can find a way to order one to be sure.

I updated the question with dimensions and pincount. As for the datasheet, as I mentioned in the question the ASRock does not have one available since they were custom-made motherboards.

Comment: I think you might have nailed it. This looks like the exact connector right here: https://www.molex.com/molex/products/part-detail/io_connectors/0757840332

Comment: @TomCarpenter — I have some cables on order, but in the meantime i was able to get some pinout diagrams from ASRock. Do these help with identification?

Comment: @TomCarpenter — So I got the 8x cables with the metal head meant for external use, and they are unfortunately not the connectors that work with this board.  It is possible that the connectors for internal connections work with this board, but I have not been able to find a good place to purchase them to try them.